# Create generic method for specified class names

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to create generic method for specified classes. Pseudo-code could be like below:

```
void doSend(Guid g)
{
   //code    
}
void doSend(Int32 i)
{
   //code     
}
void Send<T>(T param) where T:Guid or Int32
{
    //lots of code
    doSend(param) 
    //lots of code
}
```

I do not want to copy and paste whole implementation to change only one line.

Comment: It is not possible to make any or's in generic where

Comment: Not possible with Generics.  How much code could possible be similar with `Guid` and `int` data types?

Comment: @DStanley all logging, error handling, etc.

Comment: I think abstract factory pattern resolves this problem. check http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx#_self1

Answer (score 2):

Is there not a reason you can do this?

```
void Send(Guid param)
{
    ChunkA();
    doSend(param);
    ChunkB();
}

void Send(Int32 param)
{
    ChunkA();
    doSend(param);
    ChunkB();
}

void ChunkA()
{
  //lots of code
}

void ChunkB()
{
  //lots of code
}
```

Also, if you're expecting only those two types... using generics would be a slight abuse of it. You might want to step back and rethink your design.

**Edit:**
Since you mentioned in the comments that the code in common is logging and error-handling, I think it makes even more sense to make an overload of `Send` for `Guid` and `Int32`. You could have a `Send` method that looks more like this:

```
void Send(Guid param)
{
    try
    {
        LogSend(param);
        doSend(param);
    }
    catch (SendException e)
    {
        HandleSendException(e, param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to copy and paste whole implementation to change only one line.

Then don't.  Move all of the *common* code into one or more methods, call those methods from the entry points, and leave only the implementation *specific to `Guid` or `int`* in the calling method:

```
void doSend(Guid g)
{
   //do stuff specific to `Guid`

   doSendCommon(g);   
}
void doSend(Int32 i)
{
   //do stuff specific to `int`

   doSendCommon(i);    
}

private void doSendCommon<T>(T value)
{
   // do stuff common to both
}
```

Note that `doSendCommon` can be fully generic but since it's `private` *you* control what types can be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

How about having an interface:

```
public interface IDoIt
{
    void DoIt();
}

public class Foo : IDoIt
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        this.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Bar : IDoIt
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {

    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        this.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class GenericClass<T> where T: IDoIt, new ()
{
    public GenericClass()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        obj.DoIt();
    }
}
```